# Writing an Integer Array into a File

Tags: java, arrays, bubble-sort, writetofile

I'm trying to make a method that reads the file and returns an array of integers, and then convert each line of data to an integer. Then I'm trying to sort the data using a bubble sort before taking the resulting array and writing them back into a file. I'm pretty sure my bubble sort code is right, but I'm having issues trying to write the integers back into the file... I've copied and pasted the entire code I've got below :)

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException,
    FileNotFoundException {

 String filename = "/Users/Desktop/13-2/src/pkg13/pkg2/sort.txt";
processFile(filename);
writeToFile(filename);//calls method processFile
}


public static void processFile (String file)
throws IOException, FileNotFoundException{
//String line;
 //lines is declared as a string

String filename = "/Users/Desktop/13-2/src/pkg13/pkg2/sort.txt";
try (BufferedReader inputReader = new BufferedReader (new      InputStreamReader(new     FileInputStream("/Users/Desktop/writeTofile/src/writetofile/scorewrite.txt")))) {
        String line;
        while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
            double number = Double.parseDouble(line);
        }
//Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(filename));
//int i = 0;
//while(scanner.hasNextInt()){
  // bubble[i++] = scanner.nextInt();

}
}

public static void writeToFile (String filename) throws IOException {
PrintWriter outputWriter = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(filename));

    outputWriter.println();


outputWriter.flush();
outputWriter.close();
}
private int[] array = new int[25];

public int maxi(int[]a, int first){
   int max = 0;
    for(int i=first; i<a.length; i++)
    {
        if (a[max]<a[i]){
            max =i;
        }
    }
    return max;
}

public void bubble(double number) {
    boolean a = false;
    for (int i=0; i<array.length-1; i++) {
        if (array [i]> array [i+1]) {
            int temp = array [i];
            array [i] = array [i+1];
            array [i+1] = temp ;}
        a= true;

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you are writing only one empty line to the output file here:

```
outputWriter.println();
```

You need to write all numbers from your array, but you don't even store them anywhere:

```
double number = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

after this line, the number read from input file needs to be stored in an array.

Hint snippet:

```
int i=0;
while ((line = inputReader.readLine()) != null) {
        array[i++] = Integer.parseInt(line);
    }
```

You are also mixing doubles with ints :(

You are also wrong that your bubble sort is correct :(

I suggest start with something more simple, just read the array of ints and write it back to file.